# Submitting form data into PHP with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem to displaying some dynamically created data and showing the submitted data when ajax completed.

**HTML - form.html**

```
    <form name="myForm" id="myForm">
        <strong>Skills 1</strong>     
            <div>
                <select name="Skills[]" id="Skills">
                <optgroup label="Programming">
                   <option value="">-</option>
                   <option value="Javascript">Javascript</option>
                   <option value="C++">C++</option>
                   <option value="C#">C#</option>
                </optgroup>

                <optgroup label="Multimedia">
                   <option value="Adobe Flash MX">Adobe Flash MX</option>
                   <option value="Adobe Fireworks">Adobe Fireworks</option>
                   <option value="Adobe After Effects">Adobe After Effects</option>
                </optgroup>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div>
                <input type="text" name="SkillsNumber[]" id="SkillsNumber" placeholder="Number of year using" />
            </div>

            <div>
                <select name="SkillsGrade[]" id="SkillsGrade">
                  <option value="">Select your skills grade</option>
                  <option value="Noob">Noob</option>
                  <option value="Amateur">Amateur</option>
                  <option value="Professional">Professional</option>
                </select>
            </div>            
        </div>
    </form>
<div id="result-set"></div>
```

*** This select section can be dynamically added (maximum is 3)**

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
$("#myForm").submit(function(){
    var formData = $(this).serializeArray();
    console.log(formData);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            theData: formData
        },
        url: "theresult.php",
        success: function(result){
            $("#result-set").ajaxComplete(function() {
                   $("#result-set").html(result);
               });
        }   
    }); 
    return false;
});
```

**PHP - theresult.php**

```
<?php
   $data = $_POST['theData'];
   $enc = json_encode($data, true);

   ...
   ....
   .....
?>
```

The question is what should I do, if I have 3 select (so I have 3 Skills, 3 SkillsNumber, and 3 SkillsGrade) and showing it on #result-set. Already cracking head here.

Sorry for bad English. Newb here... :)

Comment: u can show it in a table ...

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Are you asking how to display the submitted results?

Comment: Use .serialize(), not .serializeArray().

Comment: @davidethell yeah you right.

Answer (score 1):

add a button on form like

```
<input type="button" value="submit" id="myBtn">
```

change your code like this

```
$("#myBtn").submit(function(){
```

and write your success function like this

```
success: function(result){                
     $("#result-set").html(result);
 }
```

if you want to use json data as a javascript object set your $.ajax method parameter like this `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: Haha, actually I already create the submit button, I just post a part of my form here.

Answer (score 1):

Use `parse_str` to get your data:

PHP - theresult.php

```
<?php
    parse_str($_POST['theData'], $params);
    $Skills = $params['Skills[]']; // I am not sure about [] part, test it
    $SkillsGrade = $params['SkillsGrade[]'];   
    $SkillsNumber = $params['SkillsNumber[]'];   

    echo "Skills: $Skills<br />";
    echo "SkillsGrade: $SkillsGrade<br />";
    echo "SkillsNumber: $SkillsNumber<br />";

    exit;
?>
```

and add `dataType: "html"` to your $.ajax() definition